# Python: Read data from STDIN, unless its not provided

Tags: python

I have a python program which reads from STDIN:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def my_func(data):
    print (data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    data = sys.stdin.read()
    my_func(data)
```

I see the expected results when I execute this with:

```
cat file.txt | ./app.py
```

I want to add some other functionality to the program:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    data = sys.stdin.read()
    if data:
        my_func(data)
    else:
        print ('I am some other functionality')
```

However when I execute this with:

```
./app.py
```

... the program just hangs, as if it is waiting for STDIN input.

What's the correct way to write this, so it will handle both methods of executing.

Comment: It is waiting for an end of file marker, to signal the end of the input to be expected. There is no way for Python to know if you are just a slow typer, or whether you're not planning to type anything on standard in. You should either use a different means of streaming in the data, or perhaps implement a timer that assumes no data will be coming in after a very short timeout.

Comment: Accept different command line arguments for the two cases.

Comment: A common way is to signal an end of file on input: `./app.py < /dev/null` on an Unix-like,

Answer (score 0):

As @Klaus D. suggested, using different command line arguments should be the most straightforward option.

`sys.argv[i]` returns the argument at index `i` used when launching the script. Index `0` is always the script name while any other index represents subsequent arguments passed to the script. With that in mind:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    objective = sys.argv[1]
    if objective == 'read':
        data = sys.stdin.read()
        if data:
            my_func(data)
    else:
        print ('I am some other functionality')
```

Answer (score 0):

Many Unix-style programs look for a dash `-` to indicate input from stdin. So,

```py
import sys

if sys.argv[1] == '-':
    read_from_stdin()
else:
    other_action()
```

```sh
$ ./app.py - < /path/to/input
```